# Delay in display for dynamically created rows for table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am attempting to populate the rows of HTML table in increments of 50 using a For Loop. The For Loop works as expected but none of the rows of the table display until the loop terminates.

```
function a() {
    // .....
    let number_of_rows = 10000
    for (i = 50; i < number_of_rows; i += 50) {
        b(i)
    }
    // .....
}

function b(start_row) {
    //create rows dynamically and append to the html table
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is *blocking* by default. The browser will only repaint once the JavaScript has finished running to the end of the synchronous code currently running. So, if you have synchronous code that, in all, inserts 10000 rows, those rows will all appear at once after everything is finished.

If you want to render the batches of 50 one at a time, add a small delay in between the calls of `b`:

```
async function a() {
    // .....
    let number_of_rows = 10000
    for (i = 50; i < number_of_rows; i += 50) {
        await b(i)
    }
    // .....
}

function b(start_row) {
    //create rows dynamically and append to the html table
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 50)); // wait 50ms
    // adjust this number as desired
}
```